# Como mostrar la seleccion previa al momento de cargar el combobox c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, combobox

Tengo la siguiente duda ya que al momento de cargar mi combobox para el ingreso de un nuevo paciente no existe problema y lo realizo de la siguiente manera.

```
     public string[] Cargar_Lista_Comuna(int codEmp)
 {
     ATENDICA_Entities db = new ATENDICA_Entities();
     try
     {
         return db.TBL_AREA.Where(x => x.EMP_ID == codEmp).OrderBy(x => x.AREA_NOMBRE).Select(x => x.AREA_NOMBRE).ToArray();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         _ = MessageBox.Show("ERROR : " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
         return null;
     }
 }
```

Pero al momento de editar el mismo paciente reutilizo el mismo método para llamar la lista de item para poder cambiarlo de area, pero al visualizar lo ingresado siempre se me posiciona en el primer item de acuerdo al query realizado en el método `Cargar_Lista_Comuna`, adjunto como realizo la carga del mismo en el método load, adicional si pongo la linea que dice valueMember me arroja el siguiente error.

> System.ArgumentException: 'No se puede enlazar con el nuevo miembro de
> presentación. Nombre del parámetro: newDisplayMember'

```
cmbArea.DataSource = daoPac.Cargar_Lista_Comuna(Convert.ToInt32(txtIDEmpr.Text));
cmbArea.DisplayMember = "AREA_NOMBRE";
cmbArea.ValueMember = "AREA_NOMBRE"; -- MARCA ERROR SI NO LA COMENTO
```

De antemano agradezco su atención y espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta consulta:

```
return db.TBL_AREA.Where(x => x.EMP_ID == codEmp).OrderBy(x => x.AREA_NOMBRE).Select(x => x.AREA_NOMBRE).ToArray();
```

Devuelve un array de string (a causa del select), entonces tu tienes algo así: `{"nombre1","nombre2","nombre3"}`

Por otro lado `ValueMember` y `DisplayMember` establece el nombre de la **PROPIEDAD** con que se enlaza a cada objeto.

Tu objeto es un `string` y un string no cuenta con la propiedad `AREA_NOMBRE`

Entonces tu funcion debe retornal una lista de objetos con propiedades, más que mal C# es orientado a objetos.

Digamos que tu colección `db.TBL_AREA` devuelve objetos del tipo `TBL_AREA`, tu función debería ser:

```
public IEnumerable<TBL_AREA> Get_lista_comunas(int codEmp)
{
    ATENDICA_Entities db = new();
    try
    {
        return db.TBL_AREA.Where(x => x.EMP_ID == codEmp).OrderBy(x => x.AREA_NOMBRE);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _ = MessageBox.Show("ERROR : " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return Enumerable.Empty<TBL_AREA>();
    }
}
```

Luego

```
cmbArea.ValueMember = cmbArea.DisplayMember= "AREA_NOMBRE";
```